# how to export the one contact from thunderbird to vcf?

Tags: thunderbird, contacts

Thunderbird 52.6.0 (32-bit)

I need to exprot the one (only one!) contact from Thunderbird adress book to the one .vcf-file ("one Person === one file").

How I can to do this?

Comment: I don't have thunderbird, but, if you are just doing one person, just transfer their information to this online [vcard maker](http://vcardmaker.com/) and then generate the vcf file. This is an efficient method in small quantities.

Comment: sorry, online services - aren't the right way for contacts (imho)

Comment: Right but you just need one? Or do you have to do a whole bunch?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to export one contact in a .vcf format is:

1. Open Thunderbird > Address Book
2. Create `New List`
3. In the new list window, there are lines to add email addresses. Add the one you want to export.
4. Press OK and then Open the new list you made on the left sidebar. There should be only the email listed that you added.
5. Go to Tools > Export > Name your file and choose `vCard (.vcf)` as the file type. (Later versions, you can just right click on the list and choose export, credit [@user5534993](https://superuser.com/users/605131/user5534993))

Comment: For version 115.6.1 right click on the list to do the actual export (step 5).